# CASE-Statement in WHERE Clause not working what am I missing?

Tags: sql, case

Trying to use a `CASE` statement in the `WHERE` clause and it's giving me errors. What did I miss?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        Commodity,
        Commodity_ID, 
        [Description],
        Train,
        Truck
FROM    dbo.List_Commodity
WHERE
        CASE WHEN @Truck = 1 THEN
            Truck = @Truck
        WHEN @Train = 1 THEN
            Train = @Train 
        END
```

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that returns **one of several possible ATOMIC values** - it's **not** a control-flow statement to handle code execution ....

Comment: @marc_s - Am thinking about how to explain the current mistake well explained thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `CASE` statement use `AND/OR` logic to do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT commodity, 
                commodity_id, 
                [description], 
                train, 
                truck 
FROM   dbo.list_commodity 
WHERE  ( @Truck = 1 
         AND truck = @Truck ) 
        OR ( @Train = 1 
             AND train = @Train )
```

In case you want to retrieve all the records when both `@Truck` and `@Train` are not equal to `1` then add the below condition to above query

```
        OR ( @Train <> 1 
             AND @Train <> 1)
```

Comment: sorry for delay went to lunch. Yeah I think I had something similar originally but when I goggled a solution everyone was using Case statements

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting that `THEN truck = @Truck` will return `true` or `false` then you are missing the fact that MS SQL has no boolean data type and no boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the `CASE` statement, following query can be helpful:

```
DECLARE @Truck INT = 1  -- 1 is an example
DECLARE @Train INT = 1  -- 1 is an example

SELECT  DISTINCT
        Commodity,
        Commodity_ID, 
        [Description],
        Train,
        Truck
FROM    dbo.List_Commodity
WHERE   1 =
        (
            CASE
                WHEN @Truck = 1 AND Truck = @Truck THEN 1
                WHEN @Train = 1 AND Train = @Train THEN 1
            END
        )
```

P.S.: Please note that the `CASE` statement only returns a value which should be compared it here.